# Is it possible to describe ALPS entity fields as required using Spring Data Rest

Tags: java, spring, rest, spring-data-rest, api-design

[SDR](https://spring.io/projects/spring-data-rest) publishes an [ALPS](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-amundsen-richardson-foster-alps-02) profile. This profile is partwise customizable according to [the official documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/rest/docs/current/reference/html/#metadata.alps.descriptions), thus custom field descriptions may be added. Is there a possibility to customize the profile further in a way that it expresses whether fields are optional or required?

I understand that I could go for a work-around, such as abusing the `description` field. However, I'm rather searching for a *non-hacky* solution, though I'm aware that such isn't included in the [latest ALPS draft](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-amundsen-richardson-foster-alps-02).

Comment: Did you ever find this out? I am also in the same problem, and currently using @Description annotation and passing a stringified json as description to create a generic framework in angular.

Comment: Hi, unfortunately not. I tried back then to replace the SDR beans that create the descriptions in the profile, but it's hard to do that. Too much `private` and/or `final` for a non-hacky solution. We finally turned away from using the profile, since it simply didn't return enough useful information and built an alternative endpoint providing all required info, collected using Java reflection. So in total, we're not reading the profile at all.

Comment: I was able to enrich the alps data by following: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33397920/spring-data-rest-custom-json-schema-alps/38632114#comment116877541_38632114

The ext object is useful for adding author specific detail